# Get img src from input box into a div

Tags: javascript, src, inputbox

The idea behind this small project of mine is to have an user enter an URL for an img, when the user hits a button the img should then be inserted into a new `<div>` within the page.

I tried looking for hours at stackoverflow but I honestly don't understand how I can use other answers to my own code. Most of the CSS and HTML code is already done, I just need help with the javascript part if its possible at all.

Here is what I have so far:

HTML code:

```
<form name="imgForm">
  enter URL:
  <input type="text" name="inputbox1" value="src" />
  <input type="button" value="Get Feed" onclick="GetFeed()" />
</form>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function GetFeed(imgForm) {
    var imgSrc = document.getElementById("src").value;
  }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out? I dont know where to go from here.. at least give me some pointers how can i get the value from the txt box and add a new
`<div><img src="user input from txt box should go here"/></div>` for every time an unser inserts and new URL for an img?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think according to your need `how can i get the value from the txt box and add a new <div><img src="user input from txt box should go here"/></div>` you need this

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="txt">
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="Get Image" onclick="getImg();" />
</form>
<div id="images"></div>
```

**JS** (goes inside your head tags)

```
function getImg(){
    var url=document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    var img=document.createElement('img');
    img.src=url;
    div.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(div);
    return false;
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cBJXn/4/).   ​

Comment: This works great, Thanks a lot, i think the hardest part for me was creatElement and appendChild, i see what you did there I can finally move to the next phase of my small project.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `id` attribute to your `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" name="inputbox1" id="box1" value="src" />
```

...then, adjust your code:

```
var imgSrc = document.getElementById('box1').value;
```

Once you have the source, you can get back an object for the `img` tag, and set its properties using the value from the text box. The `img` object's properties are defined by the Document Object Model:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will create a div with an image element that has a src equal to the text in the input box.  It then appends the div to end of the page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetFeed(form){
            var imgSrc = form.elements["inputbox1"].value;  
            var imgDiv = document.createElement('div');
            imgDiv.innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + imgSrc + "\"/>"
            document.body.appendChild(imgDiv);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="imgForm">
            enter URL:
            <input type="text" name="inputbox1" value="src" />  
            <input type="button" value="Get Feed" onclick="GetFeed(this.form)"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your codes better should be like this:
html Codes:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-5" style="margin: 0px auto;">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-image">
              Choose
      </button>
    </div>
   <input type="text" id="image_label" class="form-control" name="image" aria-abel="Image" aria-describedby="button-image" onclick="getImg()">
</div>
<div id="image-holder">
   <img id="imgThumb" class="img-thumbnail" src="{{Your Image Source}}" alt="">
</div>
```

js Codes:

```
function getImg(){
        var url = document.getElementById('image_label').value;
        var img = document.getElementById('imgThumb');
        img.src = url;
        return true;
    }
```