# Using a Text Box, HTML and Javascript to Display a PDF in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe, form-fields

I am trying to add a form (just a text box) within a Sharepoint page that requires a user to enter the url of a PDF document that will then display in an iFrame on the same page.

I've found code to do this with an image, but I'm having a difficult time modifying it to display a PDF in an iFrame.

The code I'm trying to modify comes from a previous question.  Here is the link:

[Get img src from input box into a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881477/get-img-src-from-input-box-into-a-div)

And here is the code without creating an iFrame.  I'm not sure where that should be put into this code.  Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function getImg(){
    var url=document.getElementById('txt').value;
    var div=document.createElement('div');
    var img=document.createElement('img');
    img.src=url;
    div.appendChild(img);
    document.getElementById('images').appendChild(div);
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="txt">
  <input id="btn" type="button" value="Get Image" onclick="getImg();" />
</form>
<div id="images"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an `<img>` tag, create an `<object>` tag:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">

        function getImg(){
            var url=document.getElementById('txt').value;
            var div=document.createElement('div');
            var obj = document.createElement('object');
            obj.data = url;
            obj.type = 'application/pdf';
            div.appendChild(obj);
            document.getElementById('images').appendChild(div);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txt">
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Get Image" onclick="getImg();" />
</form>
<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Joachim!  

But this still doesn't display anything in my iFrame (or anywhere else).  How does this get displayed?

Thank you again!

Comment: It should work in modern browsers.Which one do you use?

Comment: I replaced the code snippet by a complete code sample - successfully tested with Safari 9.1 and Firefox 46 on OSX.

Comment: That might be the issue.  I'm using IE 11.

Comment: Successfully tested in Chrome 50 on OSX; but sure, IE might not have an adequate PDF viewer embedded, and Chrome on Windows may differ as well. If you want to support clients w/o having an pdf viewer included or installed separately, you need to use a javascript based viewer like http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/